# How to create an exit button in a full screen swf file?

Tags: actionscript-3, button, exit

I'm currently making my thesis in Flash. Does anyone know how to put a warning before quitting the app? Like when a user clicks the "X" button, a "Are you sure you want to quit? Yes? No?" will pop up? Also, it is on a f

So far, my code for the Exit button is

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, CloseApp);
function CloseApp(e:MouseEvent) {
fscommand("quit");
}
```

hence, when click, it automatically closes the app. Thank you very much!

Comment: this will work only on the "quitting" triggered from within flash (with fscommand) but will not work when user will use close window button. For this you could look into some external exe wrapper, like MDM Zinc or create an AIR output. That way you can capture the "exiting" moment and then show the alert.

Answer (score 1):

The following piece of code illustrates how to achieve this result using Adobe AIR & Flex SDK.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                   closing="onClosingMainWindow(event)">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.CloseEvent;
        protected function onClosingMainWindow(event:Event):void
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            Alert.show('Are you sure?','',Alert.YES|Alert.NO,null,function(event:CloseEvent):void{
                if(event.detail == Alert.YES)
                    nativeApplication.exit();
            });
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

And the same result using Adobe AIR in Flash Pro. (Pure AS3)

```
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import flash.events.Event;

//activeWindow will be null until the frame will not be constructed.
stage.addEventListener(Event.FRAME_CONSTRUCTED, onFrameConstructed);

function onFrameConstructed(event:Event){
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.FRAME_CONSTRUCTED, onFrameConstructed);

    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.activeWindow.addEventListener(Event.CLOSING, onClosingMainWindow);
}

function onClosingMainWindow(event:Event):void
{
    event.preventDefault();

    //The following code will close the app.
    //NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import flash.events.Event;

addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, CloseApp);

function CloseApp(e:MouseEvent) {
    stage.nativeWindow.close();
}
```

should do the job

Answer (score -1):

//Just add following script in button

href="javascript: history.go(-1)"